# Draw rectangle/box on specific time in a day

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm trying to display a box based on specific time in a day.
The box should be displayed let's say between 9-12am (options to choose how many previous days to be displayed), top and bottom values for the box to be taken from the open of hour 2 and 4. I've made a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa19U.png) to illustrate better what I want to achieve. Basically what's marked in yellow square.
I've used the code bellow just for top and bottom values, but I can only get the values from the current day...

```
//@version=5
indicator("SSS", overlay=true)
var op1 = 0.0
var op2 = 0.0

op1 := (hour== 2 and minute == 0) ? open : op1
op2 := (hour== 4 and minute == 0) ? open : op2


c_green = color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 80)

b1 = box(na)
if barstate.islast
b1 := box.new(bar_index[20], op1, bar_index, op2,
 bgcolor=c_green, border_width=0,border_style=line.style_dashed)
box.delete(b1[1])
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the bar index at hour 9  and then at hour 12 you can draw the box.

```
//@version=5
indicator("SSS", overlay=true)
var op1 = 0.0
var op2 = 0.0
var startindex=0
c_green = color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 80)
op1 := (hour== 2 and minute == 0) ? open : op1[1]
op2 := (hour== 4 and minute == 0) ? open : op2[1]
startindex := (hour== 9 and minute == 0) ? bar_index : startindex[1]
if (hour== 12 and minute == 0) 
    box.new(startindex, op1, bar_index, op2,bgcolor=c_green, border_width=0,border_style=line.style_dashed)
```